# code 401, login required, while using YouTube Data API V3 on Android

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I am trying to use the new Youtube Data API on Android  to retrieve the Video title from a given ID,

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=6DbS1VB8HGo&part=player&key=XXX

However I keep getting getting a response saying that login required and error code 401.

Am guessing that it has something to do with the authorization token, but I don't understand why I should need this since I am not performing any account specific operations such as updating or deleting from a playlist. All I want is the title and maybe the number of view.

Any help should be appreciated, below is the code I am using:

```
public class NetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //param[0]= "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=6DbS1VB8HGo&part=player&key=xxyy"
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        HttpResponse response;

        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(responseString);
            responseJSON.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) says:

Prerequisites

1. Register your application with Google so that it can submit API requests.

Comment: sorry am new to this, but isnt the fact that i have an API key means that the is registered. I had already used this key on the new Youtube  player API for the android and it worked fine.

Comment: @Axarydax I have already done registering app on console as well as turned on YouTube Data API v3 & Google+, but still getting 401 error YouTubeSignUpRequired.